# mysqli_query of update statement isn't working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have written code with an update statement but it doesn't affect the database. I have tried with and without single quotes but it still doesn't update the database. I have by default value of Details="Order Placed" in the table but when I update the value with the update query it doesn't work.

```
<?php
include("connection1.php")
?>

<form method="POST">
Enter Orderid to be updated<br>
<input type="text" name="id">
<br>
<input type="radio" id="m" name="info" value="placed">
<label for="m">Order Placed</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="f" name="info" value="shipped">
<label for="f">Order Shipped</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="o" name="info" value="Delivered">
<label for="o">Order Delivered</label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $i=$_POST['id'];
 $info1=$_POST['info'];
 $query=("SELECT * FROM shipments WHERE OrderId='$i'");
 $data=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 $total=mysqli_num_rows($data);
 if($total==1)
 {
  $query1=mysqli_query("UPDATE `shipments` SET `Details`='$info1 
  WHERE`OrderId`='$i'");
        if($result==mysqli_query($conn, $query1))
        {
            echo "ORDER UPDATED";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "ORDER NOT UPDATED";
        }

    }       
}

?>
```

[image]

Comment: i have printed $info1 and it works. it also prints "Order Updated"

Comment: is data exist for that  `OrderId`... could you update `table` too...

Comment: yes. you can check image of the table

Comment: are you sure your query works? `SET Details='$info1‍‍` need end quotation

Comment: @Kamran thats just copy paste mistake during posting the question. i have written end quotation...actually its first time for me for posting the question

Comment: @TechnosoftPatel table structure...??? is anyone of your `echo` works...???

Comment: yes i have printed every variable successfully.

Comment: is it always echoes `ORDER NOT UPDATED` ???

Comment: have you included your action tag?

Comment: @codefather action is not necessary if query written in same page...

Comment: i think the problem is that there is no second argument, you need to pass the connection first then your query like this, mysqli_query(connection, query, resultmode), resultmode is not really necessary

Answer (score 1):

Just remove unwanted `mysqli_query` in Update statement `$query1`...

**Change**

```
$query1=mysqli_query("UPDATE `shipments` SET `Details`='$info1 
  WHERE`OrderId`='$i'");
```

**To**

```
$query1= "UPDATE shipments SET Details ='$info1' WHERE OrderId='$i'";
```